# Making Twitter Bootstrap slider load long list of pictures from MySQL efficiently

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Twitter's Bootstrap slider loads all files on list on refresh. Would it not be better to ONLY load THREE files from list?

1. Active img.
2. Next img.
3. Previous img.

This way slider is ready to produce next image in either direction, since it's all cached on first refresh. After pagination, the time spent by user 'looking' at picture could be used for caching only 'ONE' at a time ahead of active picture in list, and so on.

Avoiding long lists of images - user may just want to look at a few.

Any one know how this could be done using PHP MySQL? Is there a a plug-able JS script? - have no knowledge in JS/jquery/AJAX etc...  :-(

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

"Anyway is there a better way to do this?"

If you feel there is a better way to do something - do it. I would look at putting the image src strings into an array, then referencing them by their index.

Comment: Thanks for reply, don't want to reinvent the wheel, unless it's necessary...or running away from dinosaurs...

Comment: Got that far, just don't know how to query data base, while user is staring at active picture...not familiar with JS...

Comment: Return all images from the backend in a single request as a JSON array

Comment: JSON? Backend? Got image list nicely ordered & scaffolded with div's on first query. Now about that backend....?

Comment: Sorry i misread your earlier comment, I thought you were already returning information from your database.